# how to add same xml code Automatically in xml tags in kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, xml-parsing, custom-controls

I want to add following xml code in my xml file, TextView tags automatically, how can I do that?

**code that I want to add after opening tag is:**

```
com.mycompany.projectname.
```

**Tag in which I want to insert above code is:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
/>
```

**My expected output is as follow**

```
<com.mycompany.projectname.TextView
android:id="@+id/textView16"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom widget android studio  wont take/add automatically in XML.
you have to manually give your class name with package.

In pre-defined widget if you want to add some properties press

> Ctrl + Space        for windows
>
> Command+ space       for mac

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify resource files (including xml layouts) at runtime.

However you can install a custom [LayoutInflater.Factory2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory2) in your `Context` to modify XML parsing behavior. Sample below (note that I'm using Kotlin extensions):

**activity_style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTest"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**sample.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import com.github.ppaszkiewicz.testvhpayload.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_style.*

class StyleActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // replace default factory with a wrapper - must be called before onCreate
        layoutInflater.factory = MyTextViewFactory(delegate)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_style)
        Log.d("TEST","TextView is ${txtTest::class.simpleName}")
        Log.d("TEST","Button is ${btnTest::class.simpleName}")
    }
}

class MyTextViewFactory(val appCompatDelegate: AppCompatDelegate) : LayoutInflater.Factory2{
    override fun onCreateView(parent: View?, name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
        if(name == "TextView")
            return MyTextView(context, attrs)  // custom behaviour for TextViews
        return appCompatDelegate.createView(parent, name, context, attrs) // default appcompat views
    }

    override fun onCreateView(name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
        return onCreateView(null, name, context, attrs)
    }
}

class MyTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

After running logs should show

```
TextView is MyTextView
Button is AppCompatButton
```

Comment: I don't want to this thing.

Comment: I hope you have understood my question.

Comment: @UsmanHassanChattha you mentioned Kotlin and used xml-parsing tag so I assumed you mean runtime, otherwise what you're looking for is crude find+replace in project source files.

Comment: how would I parse xml at runtime?

Comment: @UsmanHassanChattha runtime layout XML parsing is already done by `LayoutInflater` class, my answer shows explicitly how to modify its behavior within `AppCompatActivity` to have `TextView` tags in XML inflated as a custom class.